# Why do I get "Looking up a deactivated widget's ancestor is unsafe" on my PopupMenuItem?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a Flutter page/widget, with a search box and a ListView populated from a [flutter_bloc](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_bloc) BLOC.
When text is entered, I call a BLOC method to search for results, and the result is presented in a ListView.
[image]
When I click on the `PopupMenuItem` inside the `ListTile` item I get:

[image]

> Looking up a deactivated widget's ancestor is unsafe. At this point
>   the state of the widget's element tree is no longer stable. To safely
>   refer to a widget's ancestor in its dispose() method, save a reference
>   to the ancestor by calling dependOnInheritedWidgetOfExactTpye() in the
>   widget's didChangeDepencies() method.

If I replace the BLOC "dance" with a simple static list initialization of the `stations` variable, it works fine.

I am completely lost on what to do?
Can someone please give me some pointers?

**Edit**:
Here's a repro sample (Android only):
https://github.com/MagnusJohansson/bloc_test
Click on the search icon in the app, enter "test" as the search term. Click on the 3-dot menu to trigger the error (might have to click twice).
If not doing the sqlite query, and instead returning a static list (as seen in the comment in file /bloc/searchpresets/search_presets_bloc.dart line 55) it works fine.

```
class SearchPresetsPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => _SearchPresetsPageState();
}

final GlobalKey<RefreshIndicatorState> _refreshIndicatorKey2 =
    new GlobalKey<RefreshIndicatorState>();

final GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> scaffoldKey2 = new GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();

final snackBar = SnackBar(
  content: Text('Added as a favorite'),
  action: SnackBarAction(
    label: 'Undo',
    onPressed: () {},
  ),
);

class _SearchPresetsPageState extends State<SearchPresetsPage> {
  final TextEditingController _filter = new TextEditingController();
  List<Station> stations = [];

  _textInputSearch() {
    if (_filter.text.length >= 2) {
      BlocProvider.of<SearchPresetsBloc>(context)
          .add(SearchPresets(_filter.text));
    }
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    _filter.addListener(_textInputSearch);
    super.initState();
  }

  Widget buildInitialStationsInput(BuildContext context, String message) {
    return Column(children: <Widget>[
      Center(child: Text(message)),
    ]);
  }

  Widget buildLoading() {
    return Center(
      child: LinearProgressIndicator(
        value: null,
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildListView() {
    return RefreshIndicator(
      key: _refreshIndicatorKey2,
      child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(
            color: Colors.grey[300],
            alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(4.0),
              child: Text(
                "${stations.length} Stations:",
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: ListView.builder(
              itemCount: stations != null ? stations.length : 0,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                return Card(
                  child: ListTile(
                    dense: true,
                    title: Text(stations[index].name),
                    leading: IconButton(
                      alignment: Alignment.center,
                      icon: Icon(Icons.play_arrow),
                      onPressed: () async {
                      },
                    ),
                    trailing: PopupMenuButton(
                      onSelected: (value) async {
                      },
                      itemBuilder: (context) {
                        return [
                          PopupMenuItem(
                            value: 1,
                            child: Text("Add to favorites"),
                          ),
                        ];
                      },
                    ),
                  ),
                );
              },
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
      onRefresh: () async {
        BlocProvider.of<SearchPresetsBloc>(context)
            .add(SearchPresets(_filter.text));
      },
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocListener<SearchPresetsBloc, SearchPresetsState>(
      listener: (BuildContext context, SearchPresetsState state) {},
      child: Scaffold(
        key: scaffoldKey2,
        appBar: AppBar(
          actions: <Widget>[],
          title: Container(
            color: Colors.white,
            child: TextField(
              controller: _filter,
              decoration: new InputDecoration(
                  filled: true,
                  suffixIcon: IconButton(
                    icon: Icon(Icons.clear),
                    onPressed: () {
                      _filter.clear();
                      setState(() {
                        stations = [];
                        BlocProvider.of<SearchPresetsBloc>(context)
                            .add(ClearSearch());
                      });
                    },
                  ),
                  prefixIcon: new Icon(Icons.search),
                  hintText: 'Search...'),
            ),
          ),
        ),
        body: BlocBuilder<SearchPresetsBloc, SearchPresetsState>(
            builder: (BuildContext context, SearchPresetsState state) {
          if (state is InitialSearchPresetsState) {
            return buildInitialStationsInput(context,
                "Search for stations in the search box above (at least 2 characters)");
          }
          if (state is SearchPresetsLoading) {
            return buildLoading();
          }
          if (state is SearchPresetsLoaded) {
            stations = state.stations;
            return _buildListView();
          }
          if (state is SearchPresetsError) {
            return buildInitialStationsInput(
                context, state.exception.toString());
          }
          return Container();
        }),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: can you please add bloc provider and models also? having error as incomplete code

Comment: Hi @ParthDave, I've added a complete repro sample, see edit in question.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is an issue of `contexts`. It happens often with `Dialogs`, and the `PopMenu` behaves a bit similar to a dialog, but with a dialog you can pass the `context` you want and solve this problem with a `GlobalKey` and accessing the `context` of the `Scaffold`. Unfortunately here this is not possible.

Nonetheless, there is a flag on the PopMenuButton that seems to solve your issue. `captureInheritedThemes`. The [documentation](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/PopupMenuButton/captureInheritedThemes.html) states: "If true (the default) then the menu will be wrapped with copies of the InheritedThemes, like Theme and PopupMenuTheme, **which are defined above the BuildContext where the menu is shown**". That seems to be our problem, the inheritance of context.

In your *search_presets_widget.dart* file, in your `PopupMenuButton` inside the `_buildListView` method, add this line:

```
PopupMenuButton(
  captureInheritedThemes: false, // Add this line
  ...
```

Comment: Yes, I was trying many different ways of sharing/passing the contexts to the second page ('cause I had a hunch it might be the problem), but nothing seemed to change.
Adding the line you suggested seems to have fixed the problem. Thanks.

Comment: There's definitely something interesting going on in the background with the `captureInheritedThemes` and context. I definitely will be looking a bit deeper on what it's doing to understand exactly what is happening. But for now I'm happy to have helped.

Comment: But now I have a problem with the PopupMenuButton.. the onSelected event doesn't trigger!! :( It seems to trigger every 3rd click/selection or so..
Seems to be related to the virtual keyboard is being shown (due to the text input for the search box) If I hide the virtual keyboard (with the down arrow, it seems to work better)

Comment: Will you have more items on that Menu? If not, you could just use an IconButton with a star (full & empty) and some state management to manage the favourites. It would completely avoid this issue.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! I been having this issue for the longest time